# Multilingual website, how do I change the asp CommandArgument directive to html to switch languages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, localization

I have a multilingual company website (Visual Studio / VB / ASP.NET 4.0), and when, on the homepage, you click a flag, the text changes to that language and stays with you the entire session, after I made a class, BasePage.vb.  Everything works great, but the **URL never changes** .... clients.aspx remains clients.aspx although the text DOES switch to Dutch.

It's been recommended by @Aritstos to make it so it looks like **clients.aspx?lang=nl** as opposed to just **clients.aspx** in another language.

**Currently, my asp homepage hyperlinks that work look like this:**

```
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton7" runat="server"
      CommandArgument="nl" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click"
      class="flagbutton">      
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagnl.png"
      tooltip="Bekijk deze website in het Nederlands" title="Bekijk deze website 
      in het Nederlands"/>
      <img class="map" src="images/flaghovernl.png" alt=""/>
      </asp:LinkButton>
```

**I tried to change the asp links to html links, like this:**

```
     <a href="default.aspx?lang-nl" class="flagbutton">
     <img src="images/flagnl.png" alt="Bekijk deze website in het Nederlands"
     title="Bekijk deze website in het Nederlands"/>
     <img class="map" src="images/flaghovernl.png" alt=""/>
```

But that didn't work.  The page doesn't switch languages to Dutch.  And when I click on any link, say, about.aspx, the ?lang-nl disappears.  So nothing appears in Dutch.  I was told the asplinks do the javascript_dopostback? which is bad.  Can somebody please tell me how to change my links so that they **create a string at the end of the URL saying "?lang-nl"** at the end, and it stays like that through their **entire session**?  Any help would be sincerely appreciated!

PS -- here is the code for my BasePage.vb:

```
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Imports System
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Globalization
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.Web
    Imports System.Web.Security
    Imports System.Web.UI
    Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
    Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
    Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls

     Namespace Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes
      ''' <summary>
      ''' Custom base page used for all web forms.
      ''' </summary>
      Public Class BasePage
          Inherits Page
          Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
              'retrieve culture information from session
              Dim culture__1 As String =  
  Convert.ToString(Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE))

              'check whether a culture is stored in the session
              If culture__1.Length > 0 Then
                  Culture = culture__1
              End If

              'set culture to current thread
              Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =  
  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture__1)
              Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(culture__1)

              'call base class
              MyBase.InitializeCulture()
          End Sub
      End Class
  End Namespace
```

In my Global.vb, I have this:

```
  Namespace Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes
      ''' <summary>
      ''' Summary description for Global
      ''' </summary>
      Public Structure [Global]
          Public Const SESSION_KEY_CULTURE As String = "culture"
      End Structure
  End Namespace
```

In my Culture.vb, I have this:

```
  Namespace Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes
      ''' <summary>
      ''' This class provides ISO definitions for all cultures that are supported by 
    this application.
      ''' </summary>
      Public Structure Culture
          'German - Switzerland definition
          Public Const DE As String = "de"
          'English - Great Britain definition
          Public Const EN As String = "en"
      End Structure
  End Namespace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to read parameters from the url in your case is the (lang) in clients.aspx?lang=nl you can use:

```
Request.QueryString("lang")
```

this way you can use a simple if or a select case statements to determine which language the user is requesting. something like this:

```
Select Case Request.QueryString("lang")
    Case "en"
        ' switch the english
    Case "ar"
        ' switch to arabic
    Case "jp"
        ' switch to japan
    Case Else
        ' your default
End Select
```

now to keep the same language to the user as she navigates the site you can save it in a session using the code:

```
Session("lang") = "en"
```

and to read the session value use the code:

```
Dim lang as String = CType(Session.Item("lang"), String)
```

now when we combine both methods and making sure there will be no conflic:

```
' check if there is a lang value in the url
    If Request.QueryString("lang").Length > 0 Then
        Select Case Request.QueryString("lang")
            Case "en"
                Session("lang") = "en"
                ' switch the english languge
            Case "ar"
                Session("lang") = "ar"
                ' switch to arabic
            Case "jp"
                Session("lang") = "jp"
                ' sitch to japaneese
            Case Else
                Session("lang") = "en"
                ' your default language
        End Select

    Else
        ' check if there is a value in the session
        Select Case CType(Session.Item("lang"), String)
            Case "en"
                ' switch the english languge
            Case "ar"
                ' switch to arabic
            Case "jp"
                ' sitch to japaneese
            Case Else
                ' your default language
        End Select
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my question and respond with such a detailed answer, @vasa!  I'm not sure if adding a querystring is good, bad, or indifferent; once I change the language, although there is no querystring, the text stays in that language while navigating the website until I change it again.  I'm going to look more into your answer, though, and perhaps learn a thing or two in the process.  Again, I appreciate the time you took to share your knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

URL parameters are not automatically passed from one request to the next.

You need to decide whether the language is *always* passed as URL parameters, or whether you store the selected language in a Session variable.

If you choose the Session variable storage, there are again several ways to implement language selection.

In the BasePage, detect the URL parameter (e.g. lang=nl), and implement language selection like this (sorry for C# code):

```
if (Request["lang"]=="nl")
    Session["lang"] = "nl";
```

You can also use a LinkButton and implement RequestLanguageChange_Click as

```
Session["lang"] = "nl";
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

You do not mention how you actually implemented multilingual capability. In any case your code needs to analyse the value of Session["lang"] to look up the texts of all UI elements.

Comment: Hey Devio!  Thanks a ton for responding!  This is driving me crazy.  I believe I'm using sessions.  I don't know how to decipher.  I edited my question above to show what's in my basepage.vb and global.vb.  This probably makes a lot more sense to an experienced programmer like you than it does me.  I can convert the C sharp to VB.  But would you recommend placing your code somewhere in my basepage.vb?  Thanks again!

Comment: And, Devio, I implemented multilingual capacity by following the MSDN tutorial on implicit and explicit localization.  Basically, I have a bunch of files, LocalizedText.resx, LocalizedText.fr.resx, LocalizedText.de.resx, etc., and I suppose when you click the flag, it calls to that particular resource file.  I believe that's how it works.